# CodeIgniter Loading multiple variables into a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page that has pagination on it in one section and in another section, there is a multipart form that a user can upload a file with. Currently the issue is how do I load the view? The file upload requires me to load an error variable while the pagination requires a data variable. How do i solve this? Thank you.

This is my controller code :

```
function index()
{   

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $company = $this->session->userdata('company');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->model('announcement');

    $config = array();
    $config['base_url']=site_url('announcements/index');
    $config['total_rows']=$this->announcement->count($username,$company);
    $config['per_page']=5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['announcement'] = $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links(); 



    $this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
    $this->load->view('announcements',$data);
    $this->load->view('includes/admin_footer');
}

function upload()
{
    //the name on the view must be userfile
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $company = $this->session->userdata('company');
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $description =$this->input->post('description');
    $path = './assets/files/'.$company.'/announcements';
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size']    = '10000';
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    $data = array(
            'title'=>$this->input->post('title'),
            'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
            'addedby'=>$username,
            'company'=>$company,
            'dateadded'=>date('Y-m-d'),
            'published'=>'No',
            'path'=>$path
    );

    $this->load->model('announcement');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['per_page']=5;
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {

        //$error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
        $data = array(
        'announcement' => $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)),
        'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(), 
        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
        );
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
        $this->load->view('announcements',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_footer');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
        'announcement' => $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)),
        'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(), 
        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
        );
        $file_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $result = $this->announcement->create($insert);
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
        $this->load->view('announcements',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/admin_footer');
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how the data array to be passed to the view is used. Where should I place it and what is contained in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
$this->load->view('announcements',$error);
```

is the same as this:

```
$data = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
$this->load->view('includes/admin_header');
$this->load->view('announcements',$data);
```

It doesn't matter how the variable is named. It needs to be an array *and* have the `error` key.

So, to conclude, you can have a:

```
$data = array(
    'announcement' => $this->announcement->fetch_announcement($username,$company,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)),
    'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(), 
    'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
);
$this->load->view('announcements',$data);
```

Comment: So does that mean i place my pagination data array into this data array and put it in each function? Sorry, I'm quite unfamiliar with how this works.

Comment: Currently once I submit the form, errors come back from my pagination side stating that there is an undefined variable named $announcement on my view. $announcement is what is used in my foreach loop.

Comment: Updated. hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, it works! But I had to declare the announcement model again. However, my upload no longer shows any errors for some reason. I have tried submitting a form without a file but it still goes through.

Comment: You need to do the same in your `function upload()` . Only at that point the upload errors exist. Also, make sure you're not overriding your existing `$data` variable

Comment: I've updated the code. Can you take a look and see if I'm going in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: Yep, looks good. `$file_data` is unused though. Is that right?